# Redux: async and sync dispatches

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a multi-page user registration form in my react/redux app.

When a user clicks "next page," it dispatches a call to update the user's profile in the local redux store (not the server).

When they click "Submit" on the final page, I currently have a click handler along the lines of:

```
clickHandler: function(formData) {

  dispatch(updateProfileInStore(formData);

  dispatch(saveProfileToServer());
}
```

My question is: can I be 100% certain that the Redux store w/ my user profile will update before the second dispatch is called?

I'm worried that in some cases the profile might be written to my database *before* the last page of form data is added to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not guaranteed. What you could do is pass `saveProfileToServer` the new form data have it update state and send the updated form data to the server.

As per the [react documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html)

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. ... ***There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.***

Comment: A statement like this should be accompanied by references

Comment: Good advice Juan Mendes.

Comment: The OP is asking about redux not react... You might want to double check what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to add a synchronous behaviour here is to either use redux thunk or sagas. A redux thunk returns promise that resolves and in sagas, we may have to watch for success action dispatched by updateProfileInStore which needs to call saveProfileToServer.